# Why is ap available inside Applicative?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement MonadUnliftIO for Snap and analyzing Snap classes.
I discovered that ap is used for implementing Applicative while ap requires Monad and Monad requires Applicative. It looks like a loop.

I thought till now that is not possible to write such things.
What is the limit for such kind of trick?

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
  pure :: a -> f a
  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class Applicative m => Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
 
instance Applicative Snap where
  pure x = ...
  (<*>) = ap

ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This only works because `Snap` *has* a `Monad` instance (and it's actually in scope at that point).

Effectively, the compiler handles declarations in two separate passes: first it resolves all the *instance heads*

```
instance Applicative Snap
instance Monad Snap
```

...without even looking in the actual *method implementations*. This works out fine: `Monad` is happy as long as it sees the `Applicative` instance.

So then it already knows that `Snap` is a monad. *Then* it proceeds to typecheck the `(<*>)` implementation, notices that it requires the `Monad` instance, and... yeah, it's there, so that too is fine.

The actual *reason* we have `ap :: Monad m => ...` is mostly historical: the Haskell98 `Monad` class did not have `Applicative` or even `Functor` as a superclass, so it was possible to write code `Monad m => ...` that could then not use `fmap` or `<*>`. Therefore the `liftM` and `ap` functions were introduced as replacement.

Then, when the better current class hierarchy was established, many instances were simply defined by referring back to the already existing `Monad` instance, which is after all sufficient for everything.

IMO it is usually a good idea to directly implement `<*>` and definitely `fmap` *before* writing the `Monad` instance, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are imagining a cycle like this:

- `(<*>)` is implemented with `ap`
- `(>>=)` is implemented with `(<*>)`
- `ap` is implemented using `(>>=)`

And yes, if you try this, it will indeed give you an infinite loop!

However, this is not what your code block does. Its implementations look more like this:

- `(>>=)` is implemented from first principles, without using any `Applicative` functions
- `ap` is implemented using `(>>=)`
- `(<*>)` is implemented in terms of `ap`

Which is obviously fine — there’s no cycles of any sort in this set of function definitions.

One thing which might still be a bit confusing is: how can you implement an `Applicative` function in terms of a `Monad` function, when a type can only be a `Monad` if it is already `Applicative`? To answer this, let’s add explicit type signatures to your code sample (note this requires language extensions to compile):

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
  pure :: a -> f a
  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class Applicative m => Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
 
instance Applicative Snap where
  pure :: a -> Snap a
  pure x = ...

  (<*>) :: Snap (a -> b) -> Snap a -> Snap b
  (<*>) = ap

ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

The answer is now clear: we are not in fact defining `(<*>)` for just any arbitrary `Applicative` type! Rather, we are defining it for `Snap` only, which means we can use *any* function defined to work on `Snap`s — including those from the `Monad` typeclass. The fact that this function happens to be within an `instance Applicative Snap` block doesn’t matter: in all other respects, it’s just an ordinary function definition, and there’s no reason why the full range of `Snap` functions shouldn’t be able to appear in it.

Answer (score 2):

There should be some `instance Monad Snap` somewhere else. The `ap` use in the `Applicative` instance will make use of `>>=` from that instance.

In general, an instance for `Applicative` can not make use of `ap` in this way, but when then applicative is also a monad, I think it is quite common to do so, since it's convenient.

Note that, if one chooses this route, it should avoid using `<*>` or `ap` inside the definition of `>>=`, since that could lead to infinite recursion.

The fact that the two instances are mutually recursive, in some sense, is not an issue. Haskell allows mutual recursion, and this also reflects on instances. The programmer however must ensure that the recursion actually terminates, or be prepared to have a non-terminating program.